# Validacion masiva de un Datatable usando Ajax y Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

Saludos a toda la comunidad,

Tengo una duda que aun no logro resolver, les comento un poco el caso:

Tengo un datatable que se alimenta de un excel, es decir, yo cargo al servidor un excel, lo proceso y alimento un datatable. Cabe destacar que estoy usando Laravel y Jquery para esto.

El asunto es que una vez que el Datatable se cargue se debe validar cada registro del datatable para saber si cumple con ciertas reglas que estan a nivel de servidor ya definidas (cantidad de caracteres, tipo de datos que se esta enviando etc..

La validacion debe hacerse al momento de cargar el datatable y si hay algun campo que no cumple la condicion entonces debo pintar un marco rojo sobre la celda y al estilo de un tooltip indicar cual es el error, con un clic debo poder editar el campo del datatable y hacer el ajuste.

El asunto es que todo lo que les acabo de relatar lo he hecho, pero estoy estancado en la parte de validar masivamente el DataTable, les muestro un poco de codigo donde hago la validacion masiva

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },

    error: function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {

            console.log('Not connect: Verify Network.');

        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {

            console.log('Requested page not found [404]');

        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {

            console.log('Internal Server Error [500].');

        } else if (textStatus === 'parsererror') {

            console.log('Requested JSON parse failed.');

        } else if (textStatus === 'timeout') {

            console.log('Time out error.');

        } else if (textStatus === 'abort') {

            console.log('Ajax request aborted.');

        } else {

            console.log('Uncaught Error: ' + jqXHR.responseText);

        }

    }
});

function validar($td)
{
    var $this = $td;
    var $id = $this.attr("id");
    var $text = $this.text().toString();



        /*Se envia un ajax con el id y con el valor del input para validarlo en Laravel */
    $.ajax
        ({
            url: 'editable',
            type: 'get',
            async:'true',
            data: {'id': $id, 'value': $text},
            dataType: 'json'

        }).done(function (data) {
    var bandera=data.bandera;

    /*Si la bandera es 0 significa que lo agarra la validacion*/
    if(bandera==0)
    {
        $.each(data.error, function ($index, $contenido) {
            $this.attr("style","border: solid #ff1b08;");

            $this.tooltip({
                content:" "+$contenido
            });

        })


    }
    /*Si la validacion es exitosa se quita el marco rojo de error encontrado*/
    else
    {
        $this.attr("style","border-collapse: separate;");
        $this.tooltip({
            content:""
        });
    }
})
}
```

**Después de cargar el datatable dinamicamente con Jquery**

```
$("td,.edit").each(function()
  {
  validar($(this));
  })
```

**Despues que el datatable este cargado validar con un clic celda por celda donde este en rojo**

```
$("td,.edit").on("click", function () 
  {
  validarClic($(this));
  });
```

Bien el problema que tengo es que cuando estoy cargando el Excel y se esta creando el Datatable empieza a marcar en rojo en algunas celdas y en otras no, donde no lo hace me regresa un "error  500".

Lo curioso es que usando el Inspector del navegador específicamente en la pestaña de RED me da la opción de "editar la cabecera y volver a enviar", si lo hago manual envía el dato al servidor y lo valida perfectamente.

Lo mismo sucede si lo valido haciendo clic sobre la celda, envía los datos perfectamente al servidor y hace la validación sin problemas.

El problema se presenta cuando quiero hacer la validacion de manera masiva.

Existe alguna manera (ya que no conseguí nada en la documentación de ajax) de:

- Controlar el tiempo y velocidad en la que se envía los datos al servidor, digo esto por que pareciera que se satura cuando intenta de validar.
- Limpiar de alguna manera las peticiones hechas al servidor, para que empiezen de cero o esto ocurre automáticamente ya?

Cualquier otra idea que me puedan dar por favor es bienvenida, espero me puedan ayudar.